# Can the 5V and the 12V rail on a PC PSU share the ground pin? Proprietary -> standard ARGB fan connectors

Tags: power-supply, connector, rgb, ground-loop, virtual-ground

I use 6 PC case fans which I want to get out of their proprietary 6pin connection.
They are made by the budget fan manufacturer Asiahorse and connect to one of their hubs right now. But the topic surely applies other brands/situations as well.
Since they do not support PWM (although promised, but what can you do), I want to improve on the situation by separating the connections and use a hub designed for this scenario to get RGB control via SIGNALRGB or other means and PWM control via my mainboard (Asrock Steel Legend B450).

To be able to use a hub that separates PWM from ARGB, I'd need to either get adapter cables (which I could not find online) or split the cables up to standard connectors myself. This seems to be the way to go and in my understanding it's possible.
Since 3pin ARGB and 4pin PWM would add up to 7 lines, I suppose ground is shared. But... is it? In other words: to not harm my PSU or components I want to be sure that it is e.g. possible (plus actually used in the fans) that the ground of the 5V rail (ARGB) is the same as of the 12V rail (PWM). Given that this is actually the case, all would add up.
But I lack the knowledge of electronics to be sure about it or even know how to test against, so any suggestion about how to find out would be very much appreciated.

The PSUs in question would be either a Thermaltake Toughpower Grand 650W or an Enermax Revolution D.F.2 1050W.

Comment: Almost certainly everything uses the same ground, but if in doubt measure it with a multimeter and make sure you have the pins correct. No need to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, all grounds are equal and connected together in the ATX supply, at least when it has a single 12V supply rail - I have never measured ATX supplies with multiple 12V rails.

The problem might be the amount of return current unless you know it's safe.

For example if your device usea 1A of 5V and 1A of 12V, it means a single ground wire must carry full 2A of return current, and the connectors and wires need to handle it.